# Is there way to avoid repetative object creation in a multiple methods without creating object at class level

Tags: java

```
public void benzCar(boolean car,List updateCarList)
{
  if(car)
  {
    Object color=new Object();
    color.setCarColor("black");
    updateCarList.add(color);
  }
}

public void audiCar(boolean car,List updateCarList)
{
  if(car)
  {
    Object color=new Object();
    color.setCarColor("yellow");
    updateCarList.add(color);
  }
}

public void fordCar(boolean car,List updateCarList)
{
  if(car)
  {
    Object color=new Object();
    color.setCarColor("red");
    updateCarList.add(color);
  }
}
```

Here in every method a new object is being created and we are seting color(string) for car using that object.without creating object at class level,is there any way to avoid this repetative object creation in every method.Begineer here thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't call `setCarColor` on class `Object` or did you redefine a class named Object ? ALso just passe the color String as a parameter along the others

Comment: I think you should improve design of your class, have a common method for setting the color of cars.

Comment: is this code compiling ?

Comment: Add call that method for setting up the color. it will set the color based on your input

Comment: What's the point of the `car` parameter? If you don't want "to car", don't call the method.